# What would be the utility of the declare keyword in this example

Tags: typescript

I have the following `d.ts` file (notice how there's no `declare` keyword before the namespace `D3`, neither before `d3`):

```
namespace D3 {
  export interface Selectors {
    select: {
      (selector: string): Selection;
      (element: EventTarget): Selection;
    };
  }
  export interface Event {
    x: number;
    y: number;
  }
  export interface Base extends Selectors {
    event: Event;
  }
}

const d3: D3.Base;
```

In other files, I'm capable of accessing `d3`, and I understand that this is because the d.ts file has no import/export, so it's considered as a 'global script'.

I also understand that the declare keyword is used for ambient declarations where you want to use a variable that may not have originated from a TypeScript file.

What I don't understand, is why would I ever need to add the declare keyword before `d3` if things work just fine without it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that I was able to omit the declare keyword because I had `skipLibCheck` enabled in my `tsconfig.json`, which (as the name suggests) skips type checking of declaration files:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#skipLibCheck